# Email field on registration page not working

Tags: users, emails

When I try to register a new account using the standard settings for my site no matter what I put in the email field it gets highlighted in red and I can't register a new user. Has anyone experienced this before or know any solutions to this?

Comment: do you get an error displayed? or an error showing in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

1. There you must receive a message with the error. If you don't see it, please, check if your theme have enable the messages.
2. Check if the mail is not register in the site. Just try to reset the password using that email address and you will see if was registered or not.